# How to check if user has granted camera permission in React Native Android?

Tags: android, android-camera, react-native, react-native-camera

Right after the app launches, I am getting permission to use Camera from the user. But before opening camera if I check if the user has granted camera permission or not, I get the response as "false" even when it is allowed.

Here is my code:

```
PermissionsAndroid.check('camera').then(response => {
            if (response === true){
                //Open scanner
            }
            else if (response === false){
                Alert("Please enable camera permission in device settings.")
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 15):

Please try as following:

```
PermissionsAndroid.check(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA).then(response => { ..
```

and  not

```
PermissionsAndroid.check('camera').then(response => { ..
```

Answer (score 2):

First import dependencies

```
import { PermissionsAndroid, Platform } from 'react-native';
```

Then use the following code on your event

```
if(Platform.OS=="android"){
      const permissionAndroid = await PermissionsAndroid.check('android.permission.CAMERA');
      if(permissionAndroid != PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.granted){
        const reqPer = await PermissionsAndroid.request('android.permission.CAMERA');
        if(reqPer != 'granted'){
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I am using with **async**,**await** and **promise**, a little bit better to understand.

```
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';

export const checkReadContactsPermission = async ()=>{    

  //result would be false if not granted and true if required permission is granted.
  const result =  await PermissionsAndroid.check(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried above approaches but the return type of requesting permissions is changed to boolean value.

```js
const permissionAndroid = await PermissionsAndroid.check('android.permission.CAMERA')
if (permissionAndroid != PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.granted) {
  ...
} // this doesnt work
```

instead do this

```js
const permissionAndroid = await PermissionsAndroid.check('android.permission.CAMERA')
if( permissionAndroid ){
...
}
```